# C# Xamarin: Failed to override ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, IWebResourceRequest)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I've a `class` which implements `Android.Webkit.WebViewClient` in my C# Xamarin project. However, the following error show up after I built the project with a fresh-install Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 in another machine:-

`'CustomWebViewClient.ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, IWebResourceRequest)': no suitable method found to override`

I guess it's due to the installed AVD API Level as the previous overload was deprecated in Android Nougat but I'm not sure how to fix it. Can someone throw me some light?

Additional info:-

- Installed AVD (Android 6.0 | API Level 23)
- Overload `bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, string)` (this should be marked `obsolete` but it's not the case when I check the class definition in `Mono.Android.dll`)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the ShouldOverrideUrlLoading override  into CustomWebViewClient class, if you want to have access to your webview from this class the override has the webview in the parameters.

Comment: Yes I've both override in the `class` but failed to build the project.

Comment: Glad that I've found the solution and thanks Ricardo for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Alright I think I've found the solution. I need to download the latest API Level via **Android SDK Manager** as the project was set to compile using the latest platform by default which is missing in the new machine.